# Diffrence Did download and downloaded

Tags: questions

Which one is correct way of asking question?

a ) From which site you downloaded this file ?

Or

b) From which site did you download this file ?

Similarly,

a) From where you got my number?

And

b) From Where did you get my number?

Comment: Also related: _[Survived vs Did survive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150930/); [Decided vs Did decide](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118336/); [Call vs Did call](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56351/); [Danced vs Did dance](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/144372/); [Found out vs Did find out](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/138234/); [I did try vs I have tried](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46538/); [Why did you take it? vs Why are you taking it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73661/)_

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, **b**.

It's a rule of English to add the auxiliary verbs *"did, do/does and will"* when asking questions.

"did" is for **past**
"do/does" for **present**
"will" **future**.

What I think that might have confused you was the fact that the preposition *from* was moved towards the head of the phrase, which is not very common in informal speech.

It is normal in formal speech tough; prepositions tend to appear before the relative pronoun (*which, where, who, whom*...), considering that the relative pronoun is the object of the preposition.

In your sentences, you are asking for the object of the preposition **from**, which is the only field that must be completed:

Did you download this file from "**field that must be completed**".

Comment: What about   From where you got my number? And From where did you got my number ?

Comment: In order to make it easier for you, let's put the relative pronouns and prepositions aside: **Did you get my number?**, the auxiliary *did, do/does, will* always comes before the subject of the main sentence. In that case, it is **you**. So the auxiliary **did** comes before it. Now, we must put the verb into its normal form, not in the past because **did**, which already implies past, has been added, so we already know that the sentence is in the past tense: **Did you get**. You used the past of **get**, which is **got**, even though **did** has already been added. And that's wrong.

Comment: While Studying on my query I come across Something called embedded questions. E.g. Can you tell me from where you got my number ?

Comment: @user4084 - In that case, the clause **from where you got my number** is a *Dependent Clause* (a.k.a: *Subordinate Clauses*), they have different functions (which I will address below). In that case, it is a *noun* acting as the object of the verb **tell**. 
Subordinate clauses have three different functions: *Nominal, Adjectival and Adverbial*. Nominal: **Can you do *what I asked you?*** / Adjectival: **The guy *to whom I talked* talked to me**. / Adverbial: **I will talk to you *when I get home***.